# Android image slider daimajia clear cache

Tags: android, caching, slider, picasso

I have implemented diamajia slider library.and i am getting image from server.

From the JSON data i display image in diamajia slider.But i want to clear the cache when image is changes from server but the url is same as it is.Only image is changed.so how can i change image when image is changed at server side.

Or i want to clear the cache..

The same problem i get while using picasso library.In picasso and diamajia  i also want to clear the cache if image is changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load("your_image_url")
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
.into("your_image_view");
```